# Nested Dictionary in Python - error-ridden

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, syntax-error

I've spent hours trying to understand how to nest dictionaries properly in Python when they're more complex. I'm trying to build a practice dictionary with the following, but it has many errors, despite it being logically written to me:

```
my_dict = {
    0: {
        "Artist": "Pat Metheny",
        "Album": {"Offramp", "First Circle"}
    },
    1: {
        "Artist": "William Ackerman",
        "Album":
            {
            "title": "Imaginary Roads",
                "Year": "1986",
            "title": "Passage",
                "Year": "1979"
            }

        },

    2: {
        "Artist": "John Coltrane",
        "Album":
            {
            "title": "A Love Supreme",
                "Year": "1960",
            "title": "Ballads",
                "Year": "1966"
            }

        }
}

    for x, y in my_dict.items():
        print(x, my_dict[x]['Artist'])
```

I got this to work without errors, except now I have duplicate keys for 'Year'. Should I have it 'title1', 'title2' and so on?  How about 'Year'?

Comment: You have values without keys (or keys without values) like `1: {"Imaginary Roads",  "Year": "1986"},` What is `Imaginary Roads`?

Comment: On a related note, this value is a set: `"Album": {"Offramp", "First Circle"}`

Comment: Using an integer sequence as keys for dictionaries is not recommended. Use a list instead.

Comment: So, I used 'title' instead of an integer. Now how do I make it so the duplicate keys aren't a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, key value for no: 2 is missing a last curly brace at the end that will close the dict.

```
 {
   2: {
       key: value,
       key: value

   }

 }
```

The key: value here represents your content for key no: 2 btw...
(got fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary in Python are pairs of keys and values, therefore you will need to provide both for each pair, separated by the colon symbol (`:`).

So for example you are writing `"Album": {"Offramp", "First Circle"}`, The key is `Album` - Good, and the value is another Dictionary, but its format is not pair of `key: value`, instead what you may want is a `list` object (an array of elements separated by commas), which is `"Album": ["Offramp", "First Circle"]`. Same thing with other parts, e.g

```
 {"Imaginary Roads",
  "Year": "1986"}
```

You can either update this as a porper `dict`:

```
 {"name": "Imaginary Roads",
  "Year": "1986"}
```

or change to a combination of `list` and `dict` (not recommended):

```
 ["Imaginary Roads",
  {"Year": "1986"}]
```